# Update android appcompat library version in react-native

Tags: react-native

Can I freely change the `com.android.support:appcompat` and `buildToolsVersion` to the latest or do I need to keep them to what is present when the react-native project is created. By default the `com.android.support:appcompat` and `buildToolsVersion` is `23.0.1` and the current latest version is `25.0.0`. I need to access some APIs which are introduced in `appcompat` version `24.0.0` and wanted to check if I can just update the versions to the latest or could that create some problems?

Answer (score 0):

After updating the Android appcompat library version to `25.0.0` and a few trial and errors, I have figured that the appcompat library version can be updated to the latest version which is currently `25.0.0` but the `targetSdkVersion` in the `android/app/build.gradle` file for the app has to be kept at `22` because of the new permission model that has been introduced in API level 23 which is not fully integrated into `react-native` yet. You may change the `targetSdkVersion` to `25` as well but you may need to add some code to explicitly request permissions for the phone resources which were granted automatically in API level 22 and below if the permission is present in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.